# Android vitals empty

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-vitals

My app doesn't install on some devices.
Unfortunately, on some devices, the installation is impossible.
I didn't restrict the phones list on Google play console, and I have no info in Android Vitals board.

Should I wait for more downloads for the system to gather data for analysis ? Or is there a way to "activate" Android vitals in the app ?
Where can I find infos about failed installations beside ?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know if "doesn't install"? got any more details?

Comment: On one of my users phone (Pixel 3GL), he got a screen saying :

"Impossible to install xxx, Try again or try these solutions (etc)"

The solutions suggested are for instance 
- to clear cache
- to reboot the phone
- to check SD card, etc

He tried all, none is working

Comment: Have you changed the process name or anything in the Android Manifest? There's so many reasons, you need to work out whats changed.

Comment: This is my AndroidManifest (generated by Unity)
[https://privfile.com/download.php?fid=620bef58127b8-MTI0ODI=]
Do you see something that prevents some devices to deny installation ?

Comment: Not 100% but this is really old school `installLocation="preferExternal"` I don't think its needed. Random guess that if they don't have an "external" SD then it can't install

Comment: Do you have more information on the types of devices that can't install the app? e.g. are they all on Android 12? 
Note: The Android Vitals section of the Google Play Console only reports Crashes and ANRs. It does not report failed installations.

Comment: Good news, we added in the manifest :

android:exported="true" 
and 
 android:installLocation="auto" 

And our AAB works now on Android 12.
Thanks a lot.